# What's an easy way to fasten/unfasten to bind two horizontal poles?

Tags: knots

I need a knot that can be fastened and unfastened as quickly as possible (like a toggle on a jacket; twist and release). I also need to be able to tighten or loosen the rope easily. Basically, I want a rope that works how a seatbelt works.

I can only envision a loop at one end and a "stopper" at the other end, like one, might find in a bracelet. Here's an example of what I mean.

[image]

Then I would need to be able to tighten this loop.

My goal is to bring two horizontal poles close together by looping a rope around them.

This seems like such a simple concept and yet my searches have proved fruitless, likely because I don't even know where to begin with knot fundamentals (from my Scouts days I have retained nothing more than the reef knot!).

Answer (score 8):

If speed is the goal here, then just use a nylon belt with a buckle. To shorten just cut one end and then seal it with a lighter.

[image]

[Source](https://www.strapworks.com/default.asp)

Easy on and off and if you need more security wrap it twice before buckling.

Answer (score 5):

There's one more old scout knot that applies in this case, the pole hitch.

A bit of an obscure one as it's very limited in application, the sole purpose of this hitch is to gather horizontal poles together.

Make a large 'S' in the rope under the poles such that you have an end and a loop on each side, put each end round the poles and through the opposing loop, bring the ends back together over the poles and secure the ends together with your choice of knot.

Comment: My first thought as well, but not easy to untie.  It is certainly more secure, though.

Comment: @JeffW, that's up to what knot you tie to secure the ends. Tie a bow and you just need to pull the end.

Answer (score 1):

Charles answer is the correct one for speed.

The traditional answer is a sheer lashing.  3 loose turns around the pair (or trio) of poles, then pass between the poles twice, pull tight and tie off.  I wouldn't want to hold my breath while undoing this on a dark rainy night.[image]

The image above has more turns around the poles than I would normally use.

Comment: You do not want to do a sheer lashing in a situation you need speed, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about repurposing an old belt.  Add a few more holes to it.

Comment: Hi Sherwood! Was this meant to either be an edit to your answer above, or perhaps a comment based on what Willeke said? It came up in the low quality queue, and I'm hoping to head off downvotes or deletion if it was an accident!  If it was meant to be a second answer, it might be good to know it's in that queue so you can expand on it!

Comment: I think this is independent from Sherwoods previous answer and a rare instance where a one line answer is appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with steps in the adjustments you can make a loop like the bracelet but with a series of balls or loops.

Or you can put a moving knot to tighten the loop. This will not have steps but you may need to adjust before you apply.

You can see samples of both on [this page,](http://knopen.ismijnhobby.nl.bales.id.au/tables/bracelet_table.html) (my own not commercial website.) The series of ball knots and the closure knot which will allow adjustment for the length. 
You will still need to arrange them into the shape that works for you.